# How to understand these C++ statements when debugging

Tags: c++

When debugging C++ program, I see the following statements,

1. `__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<`
2. `std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >`

After googling them, I saw the similar statements, but can't find the clarifications for these statements.
Could someone give me some explanations?

Comment: Do an internet search for "C++ stream operator".

Comment: Template specialization and `operator<<` in one. There's no claiming C++ isn't "expert friendly" in the face of `operator<<<...<...> >`.

Comment: Those are not `STL` statements. The `STL` refers only to the *containers* and *algorithm* parts of the Standard Library.

Comment: The debugger doesn't make too much effort to hide implementation details from you.  It shouldn't.  These are template specializations used by the standard C++ library included with MSVC++.  Useful since using std::string is very common.  And desirable since that code can be spun off into a library (msvcpxxx.dll), normally very hard to do with templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case 1

Let's introduce some extra whitespace:

```
__imp_std :: basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > :: operator<<
```

`std::char_traits` is a class template taking one template type parameter. In this case, it's used with `char` as the argument.

This instantiation of `std::char_traits` is then used as a template type argument for the class template `basic_ostream` defined in namespace `__imp_std`. Note that since the latter contains two consecutive underscores, it's an implementation detail of the standard library in question. Most likely a namespace for **imp**lementation of **std**.

Finally, this class (instantiation of `__imp_std::basic_ostream`) has a member named `operator <<`.

So the whole piece of code is just a reference to `operator <<` declared inside a `__imp_std::basic_ostream` instantiation.

#### Case 2

Again, let's start with whitespace:

```
std :: operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >
```

This is a reference to a function template `operator <<` declared in namespace `std`. This function template apparently takes one template type parameter, and in this case, we're passing `std::char_traits<char>` as the argument for that parameter.

---

Note that strictly speaking, these aren't (complete) statements, they're just part of either a declaration or an expression.